# Lost preview in hover panel after applying custom display template

Tags: web-part, search-results, display-template, result-source, hover-panel

Similar to this question: [Custom Display Template, on one content type, lost preview on word files, powerpoint, etc](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93993/custom-display-template-on-one-content-type-lost-preview-on-word-files-powerp), I have created one content source where multiple content type data will be fetched.

Basically, first I created Result Source, which has custom query to fetch all the documents from different libraries.

Then I created result type according to my result source.

[image]

Above result type has custom item display template, which shows the data in table format.

When I select the same result source in search result webpart and hover over the item, it has no preview available for the document, From the above question link, I have tried to change the display template value but that didn't work for me. See below rendering of hover display template.

[image]

This document is PDF file, when I simply find this document in out of the box search result, it shows the preview of the document properly, but in my case it is not rendering at all.

Can someone guide me whether this is by default nature of custom display template or I am missing some configuration? If yes, what would be the steps to achieve document preview in search result record.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your custom item display template, have you configured the correct path to hover panel item template yet?

```
var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Default_HoverPanel.js";
```